# No Results from MySQL / Python Mysql Connector Only On Large Queries

Tags: python, mysql

I have a rather large query that does not return any values from my MySQL database.  Within my code, I have a dedicated SQL handler that 100% works for queries that are simple such as (select * from x).  I have done quite a bit of research but cannot find a solution as to why a larger select query wouldn't work in this case.  The query **does** work **and returns** values in the MySql Workbench but does not return anything when run from my code.  I suspect that this is a problem with the mysql.connector.  Any help with this problem will be very much appreciated.

**Python Code**

```
import mysql.connector as mysql
import Settings

def retrieve_all_rows(query_string, insert_tuple = None):
    ret_list = []
    mydb = mysql.connect(**Settings.mysql_params)
    mycursor = mydb.cursor()
    mycursor.execute(query_string, insert_tuple)
    ret_list = mycursor.fetchall()
    return ret_list
```

**Query**

```
select
    symbol, 'rsi below 30' as reason, rsi
from
(
    select
        symbol,
        date,
        gain,
        loss,
        rn,
        avg_gain,
        avg_loss,
        avg_gain / avg_loss as rs,
        100 - (100 / (1 + (avg_gain / avg_loss))) as rsi
    from
    (
        select
            a.symbol,
            a.date,
            a.gain,
            a.loss,
            a.rn,
            if(b.avg_gain is null, ((@prev_avg_gain * 13) + gain) / 14, b.avg_gain) as avg_gain,
            if(b.avg_loss is null, ((@prev_avg_loss * 13) + loss) / 14, b.avg_loss) as avg_loss,
            @prev_avg_gain := if(b.avg_gain is null, ((@prev_avg_gain * 13) + gain) / 14, b.avg_gain),
            @prev_avg_loss := if(b.avg_loss is null, ((@prev_avg_loss * 13) + loss) / 14, b.avg_loss)
        from
        (
            select
                symbol,
                date,
                close,
                rn,
                close - @prev_close as chng,
                if((close - @prev_close) >= 0, close - @prev_close, 0) as gain,
                abs(if((close - @prev_close) < 0, close - @prev_close, 0)) as loss,
                @prev_close := close
            from
            (
                select
                    symbol,
                    date,
                    close,
                    rn
                from
                (
                    select
                        symbol,
                        date,
                        close,
                        @rn := IF(@prev = symbol, @rn + 1, 1) AS rn,
                        @prev := symbol
                    from stock_data_no_blanks
                    join (select @prev := NULL, @rn := 0) as vars
                    order by symbol, date desc
                ) all_tbl
                where rn between 0 and 236
                order by symbol asc, rn desc
            ) limit_tbl
        ) a

        LEFT JOIN

        (
        select
            symbol,
            max(date) as max_date,
            avg(gain) as avg_gain,
            avg(loss) as avg_loss,
            avg(gain) / avg(loss) as rs,
            100 - (100/(1+(avg(gain) / avg(loss)))) as rsi
        from
        (
            select
                *
            from
            (
                select
                    symbol,
                    date,
                    chng,
                    rn,
                    if(chng >= 0, chng, 0) as gain,
                    if(chng < 0, abs(chng), 0) as loss
                from
                (
                    select
                        symbol,
                        date,
                        close,
                        close - @prev_close as chng,
                        @prev_close := close,
                        rn
                    from
                    (
                        select
                            symbol,
                            date,
                            close,
                            @rn := IF(@prev = symbol, @rn + 1, 1) AS rn,
                            @prev := symbol
                        from stock_data_no_blanks
                        join (select @prev := NULL, @rn := 0) as vars
                        order by symbol, date desc
                    ) as rank_tbl
                    join (select @prev_close) as vars
                    where
                        rn between 236 and 250
                    order by symbol, rn desc
                ) assorted_table
            ) minus_two_fifty
            where rn <> 250
        ) final_tbl
        group by symbol
        order by symbol asc
        ) b on b.symbol = a.symbol and b.max_date = a.date
        order by symbol asc, date asc
    ) hopefully_last
) the_last
where
    rn = 1
    and rsi < 30
    and date between sysdate() - interval 10 day and sysdate()
```

Comment: are you sure there is not a error? ...have you check the logs  or a trace ? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/query-log.html